# Consulta para obtener nombre de usuario en relación polimorfica

Tags: laravel, eloquent

tengo estas dos migraciones :

**Tabla user**

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            // $table->string('email')->unique();
            // $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            // $table->string('password');
            // $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

**Clase User**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];


    /**
     * Relaciones
     */

     public function productos(){
         return $this->hasMany(Producto::class);
     }

    public function comentarios(){
        return $this->morphMany(Comentario::class,'comentable');
    }

    public function comentariosCreados(){
        return $this->hasMany(Comentario::class);
    }
}
```

**Tabla Comentarios**

```
    <?php

    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

    class CreateComentariosTable extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('comentarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('titulo');
                $table->text('cuerpo');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('comentable_id');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('comentable_type');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }

        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::dropIfExists('comentarios');
        }
    }

**Clase comentario**

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comentario extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = "comentarios";
    protected $fillable = ["titulo","cuerpo"];


    public function comentable(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

**Clase comentarios**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comentario extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = "comentarios";
    protected $fillable = ["titulo","cuerpo"];


    public function comentable(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Pretendo saber quien creo el comentario(siempre sera un usuario) y a que cosa.

Mis dudas son las siguientes:

1. ¿Es correcto poner en la tabla comentarios un campo llamado **user_id** para saber quien lo creo? Si no es asi como sabria quien lo ha creado.
2. En el caso de que un usuario creara un comentario en el perfil de otro usuario estaria aplicando  el polimorfismo y la foranea en el mismo modelo, eso me da lugar apensar que esta mal diseñada mi tabla comentarios.

   3. Como se puede apreciar en el **modelo comentario** creo una relacion polimorfica con comentarios para guardar los comentarios asociados a ese usuario pero ocmo tambien me gustaria saber quien los ha creado meto una foranea user_id para saber el creador.

¿Que forma seria la mas optima para saber tanto a que modelo se refiere el comentario (modelo polimorfico) como para saber el usuario que lo ha creado?

**Aclaracion**

1 usuario - N comentarios (creados a otros usuarios o a otras clases) 
1 usuario - N comentarios (que le han escrito otros usuarios)

Comment: La relación que pretendes mostrar es de que tipo?, es decir: uno a uno, uno a varios o muchos a muchos, donde muchos usuarios tienen varios comentarios

Comment: ¿El usuario a qué le hace comentarios? para que podamos aplicar la relación polimórfica nos falta ese dato

Comment: @BetaM disculpa por la tardanza, voy a editar la pregunta para que se mas claro. Gracias

Comment: @BetaM ya esta hecha la aclaracion, gracia de nuevo

Comment: En la nota al final de tu pregunta dices que 1 usuario puede hacer N comentarios a otras clases (asumo que hablamos de que indicas que muchos usuarios pueden tener muchos comentarios asociados)

Comment: no exactamente, hablo de clases polimorficas, puede ser a otro usuario a un producto a un servicio a un coche lo que sea, he puesto las dos clases prolblematicas pero imaginate que los comentarios pueden hacer de muchas clases que tenga en mi sistema. La principal problematica es que quiero saber que cosas tienen coomentarios (esto funciona) pero tambien quiero saber quienes han sido los usuarios que han creado dichos comentarios en esas cosas (eso no funciona)

Comment: Ahhh ok ahora si quedó mas claro

Comment: Como pondrias tu esa relacion entonces ?

Comment: Dame un momento, estoy redactando una posible solución

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Basándonos en el código que ya tienes avanzado, considero que debería quedar así:

Tener 3 modelos

- User
- Comment
- Car

En tu migración de la tabla `comments` deja la columna `user_id` para poder identificar el usuario que realizó dicha acción, vinculándola con la tabla `users` mediante la creación de la *FK* debiendo quedar de esta forma:

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
```

Ahora para las relaciones:

Tu modelo `Comment` debe tener lo siguiente:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $table = "comentarios";
    protected $fillable = ["user_id", "titulo", "cuerpo"];
    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Colocamos el la propiedad `$fillable` los valores que pueden ser asignados de forma masiva.

Declaramos la relación inversa en el modelo `Comment` con respecto de `User`que es *pertenece a* apoyándonos de `belongsTo()`

Ahora tu modelo `User` debería estar así:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }
}
```

Modelo `Car`

```
class Car extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }
}
```

Ahora procedemos a la sección de consultas:

Consideremos que ya tenemos al menos

- Un vehículo registrado
- Un usuario registrado

Entonces queremos ver los comentarios asociados al Vehículo con `id` = 1 así:

Donde al final le encadenamos el acceso al nombre de la relación que es `comments`

```
$vehículoElegido = Car::findOrFail($idVehiculo)->comments;
```

Como en este punto un solo vehículo recuperado puede tener múltiples comentarios asociados entonces debemos iterar con un `foreach` la colección así:

```
@foreach($vehiculoElegido as $vehiculo)
    {{ $vehiculo->cuerpo }}
    {{ $vehiculo->user->name }}
@endforeach
```

Con un posible resultado en pantalla similar a esto:

```
este auto es genial y el autor es: yo
este auto es feo y el autor es: tu
este auto es bahhhh y el autor es: el
```

Con lo anterior deberías:

- Estar obteniendo todos los comentarios asociados a un vehículo
- Acceso a los nombres de los autores de los comentarios por medio de la invocación de la relación  y su propiedad `author->name`